# $ \mathbb{E} $ is a linear subspace of $ \mathbb{R^n}$. What $ \langle x, y\rangle \leq0 \implies \langle x, y\rangle= 0 $ exactly means?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$E$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n $. Let $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $. for every $ y \in E $, we have : $$  \langle x, y\rangle \leq 0 \implies \langle x, y\rangle = 0 $$ We also have the same for $\geq$ from what I understood.

I understand the proof behind it; you just need to say that $E$ is a linear subspace, so: $ y \in E \implies -y \in E $ and you find that the dot product is null. Here is my question: 
Does it mean that the dot product of $x$ and $y$, $y$ being in a linear subspace, is always null? And why is it suppose to be like this ? I don't understand the geometrical intuitions behind it.

Please, if my question is ambiguous or unclear, let me know !
Thank you very much :)

Comment: What is the operation $x\cdot y$ ? your statement doesn't make so much sense to me...

Comment: I don't understand the sentence and I think you are misreading $$[(\forall y\in E, \langle x, y\rangle\le 0)\Rightarrow (\forall y\in E, \langle x, y\rangle=0)]$$

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that the inner product of $x,y$ is zero for every subspace. Only for those subspaces where you are given $\langle x,y\rangle\le0$. Is that your question?

Comment: @Surb Let me edit it

Comment: @Gae.S. It's actually what I wanted to say, let me clarify it

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Okay I got it ! It was really unclear but it was my question. I didn't understand the proposition correctly then. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $y\in E$. Then $\langle x, y \rangle=-\langle x, -y \rangle$ (1). So either $\langle x, y\rangle$ or $\langle x, -y\rangle$ is negative. By assumption it follows that one of them is $0$. (1) then implies that $\langle x, y \rangle=0$. So $E$ is orrhogonal to $x$.

Comment: thank you very much